# FastReport высота Memo по высоте MasterData

Tags: fastreport

Есть отчет, выполненный в FastReport 4.12.6. В нем выводятся данные, которые группируются по типам (с помощью SubReport). Сам отчет работает в плане выгрузки и группировки данных. Проблема в том, что поля группы не растягиваются на свой собственный MasterData по высоте. И выглядит всё (схематично) вот так:[image: Схематичное представление результата работы отчета]

Как видно на изображении: поля 2 (название группы) и 5 (общее количество типов (указаны в поле 3 во 2й строке)) должны бы растягиваться по высоте, но этого не происходит. "Играл" свойствами StretchMode у самих Memo, и Stretched у MasterData в которые они помещены.

Структура отчета следующая:

```
MasterData
  Memo //для поля 2 (название группы)
  Subreport
    MasterData
      Memo //для поля 5 (общее количество типов (указаны в поле 3 во 2й строке))
      Subreport
        MasterData
          Memo //для остальных полей
```

Данные заттачены к MasterData и Memo (три разных запроса: группы(2), типы в группах и их количество(5), подробная информация(3,6,7))
Кодом отчета я скрываю MasterData (на OnBeforePrint) если дочерний ID не совпадает с родительским.

Более подробно расписать не могу, ибо корпоративная тайна.

Помогите советом, как растянуть Memo на всю высоту их MasterData? Ну или скажите может быть я вообще применяю не тот метод группировки, что следовало бы, ну и направьте, соответственно.

---

Прикладываю минимальный пример, который работает точно также, как и мой основной отчет (то есть неправильно, без растягивания, настройки все те же самые).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<TfrxReport Version="4.12.6" DotMatrixReport="False" IniFile="\Software\Fast Reports" PreviewOptions.Buttons="4095" PreviewOptions.Zoom="1" PrintOptions.Printer="Default" PrintOptions.PrintOnSheet="0" ReportOptions.CreateDate="43705,4791322454" ReportOptions.Description.Text="" ReportOptions.LastChange="43705,4818397107" ScriptLanguage="PascalScript" ScriptText.Text="begin&#13;&#10;&#13;&#10;end." PropData="03546F7003C0000844617461736574730100095661726961626C65730100055374796C650100">
  <TfrxDataPage Name="Data" Height="1000" Left="0" Top="0" Width="1000"/>
  <TfrxReportPage Name="Page1" PaperWidth="210" PaperHeight="297" PaperSize="9" LeftMargin="10" RightMargin="10" TopMargin="10" BottomMargin="10" ColumnWidth="0" ColumnPositions.Text="" HGuides.Text="" VGuides.Text="">
    <TfrxMasterData Name="MasterData1" Height="18,89765" Left="0" Top="18,89765" Width="718,1107" ColumnWidth="0" ColumnGap="0" RowCount="2" Stretched="True">
      <TfrxSubreport Name="Subreport1" Left="0" Top="0" Width="718,1107" Height="18,89765" ShowHint="False" Page="Page2"/>
      <TfrxMemoView Name="Memo1" Left="109,60637" Top="0" Width="94,48825" Height="18,89765" ShowHint="False" StretchMode="smMaxHeight" Font.Charset="1" Font.Color="-16777208" Font.Height="-13" Font.Name="Arial" Font.Style="0" Frame.Typ="15" ParentFont="False" Text="Group"/>
    </TfrxMasterData>
  </TfrxReportPage>
  <TfrxReportPage Name="Page2" PaperWidth="210" PaperHeight="297" PaperSize="9" LeftMargin="10" RightMargin="10" TopMargin="10" BottomMargin="10" ColumnWidth="0" ColumnPositions.Text="" HGuides.Text="" VGuides.Text="">
    <TfrxMasterData Name="MasterData2" Height="18,89765" Left="0" Top="18,89765" Width="718,1107" ColumnWidth="0" ColumnGap="0" RowCount="2" Stretched="True">
      <TfrxSubreport Name="Subreport2" Align="baWidth" Left="0" Top="0" Width="718,1107" Height="18,89765" ShowHint="False" Page="Page3"/>
      <TfrxMemoView Name="Memo3" Left="204,09462" Top="0" Width="94,48825" Height="18,89765" ShowHint="False" StretchMode="smMaxHeight" Font.Charset="1" Font.Color="-16777208" Font.Height="-13" Font.Name="Arial" Font.Style="0" Frame.Typ="15" ParentFont="False" Text="Count"/>
    </TfrxMasterData>
  </TfrxReportPage>
  <TfrxReportPage Name="Page3" PaperWidth="210" PaperHeight="297" PaperSize="9" LeftMargin="10" RightMargin="10" TopMargin="10" BottomMargin="10" ColumnWidth="0" ColumnPositions.Text="" HGuides.Text="" VGuides.Text="">
    <TfrxMasterData Name="MasterData3" Height="18,89765" Left="0" Top="18,89765" Width="718,1107" ColumnWidth="0" ColumnGap="0" RowCount="5" Stretched="True">
      <TfrxMemoView Name="Memo4" Left="298,58287" Top="0" Width="94,48825" Height="18,89765" ShowHint="False" StretchMode="smMaxHeight" Font.Charset="1" Font.Color="-16777208" Font.Height="-13" Font.Name="Arial" Font.Style="0" Frame.Typ="15" ParentFont="False" Text="Details"/>
    </TfrxMasterData>
  </TfrxReportPage>
</TfrxReport>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста не размещайте решение в вопросе. Лучше разместите как отдельный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть один вариант решения проблемы - устанавливать у `Subreport` включенным свойство `PrintOnParent` и "растягиваемому" полю нужно установить `StretchMode = smMaxHeight`. **Но этот вариант поможет вам только в том случае если вы используете только один подзапрос.** Если в подзапросе у вас еще один подзапрос, и если обоим установить `PrintOnParent = true`, то вложенный в подзапрос подзапрос (ужасно звучит, но я не знаю как описать иначе) просто не будет печататься, словно нет его вовсе. Это очень странная штука, и скорее всего недоработка самого FastReport. Так как у меня как раз случай с "многовложенностью" мне помогло другое.

После того как на 10 раз все перепроверил (гайды FastReport как не помогали, так и не помогают) нашел решение, определив OnAfterData каждого из "проблемных" Memo:

```
procedure Memo<поле 2>OnAfterData(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  Memo<поле 2>.Height := Memo<поле 3>.Height * <группы."количество объектов">;  
end;

procedure Memo<поле 5>OnAfterData(Sender: TfrxComponent);
begin
  Memo<поле 5>.Height := Memo<поле 3>.Height * <типы в группах."количество объектов">;                                                                
end;
```

Случай очень частный, но с многовложенными подзапросами работает только этот метод. За множитель высоты взял эталонный Memo, который у меня не меняется по высоте никогда, а также ему равны по высоте всегда все строки из Detail из моего примера.

Comment: Отличный ответ, держите +1!

Answer (score 1):

Для растягивания объекта по высоте бэнда, достаточно свойства `StretchMode = smMaxHeight`. Для растягивания бэнда, чтобы он вмещал свои объекты используется свойство `Stretched = True`.

Если у вас не получается, то составьте и приложите пожалуйста **минимальный пример** (без корпоративной тайны) и мы попробуем выяснить что с ним не так.

---

Похоже на косяк в FastReport, он не высчитывает высоту сабрепортов. Тут тогда 3 решения:

- обращаться в оф.тех.поддержку,
- переделать таблицу на обычную или кросс, с объединением ячеек,
- строить отчет в 2 прохода, запоминая в скрипте высоту сабрепортов в 1 проходе и назначая ее во втором.

Comment: Прикрепил файл к вопросу.

Comment: Похоже на косяк в FastReport, он не высчитывает высоту сабрепортов. Тут тогда 3 решения: - обращаться в оф.тех.поддержку, - переделать таблицу на обычную или кросс, с объединением ячеек, - строить отчет в 2 прохода, запоминая в скрипте высоту сабрепортов в 1 проходе и назначая ее во втором.

Comment: есть проблема с этими товарищами в fastreport: на все вопросы тыкают в сторону гайда, в гайде никаких подобных проблем не рассматриваются. Высота сабрепа всегда одна и та же (18,89765), вне зависимости заполненности. На форумах fastreport'a сидят какие то странные люди, которые только выпендриваются и ни решений, ни советов не предлагают. Есть ли какой-то годный, хороший, без нареканий аналог фаста?

Comment: Фаст вполне себе хорош, по крайней мере у других альтернатив все еще сложнее (например Jasper).